# How can I resume a httrack mirroring session stopped by limit?

Tags: mirroring, httrack

I was mirroring a site using HHTrack, and it ran for some time and stopped with
log containing the following:

```
<snip>
Too many URLs, giving up..(>100000)
To avoid that: use #L option for more links (example: -#L1000000)
14:48:58    Info:   Top index rebuilt (done)
```

Does it mean it didn't mirror all pages?

How do I continue the mirroring without spending unnecessary time copying the
already-mirrored files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the action continue an interrupted download/mirror after increasing the URL limit.

For the command line version:

```
Action options:
  w *mirror web sites (--mirror)
  W  mirror web sites, semi-automatic (asks questions) (--mirror-wizard)
  g  just get files (saved in the current directory) (--get-files)
  i  continue an interrupted mirror using the cache
  Y   mirror ALL links located in the first level pages (mirror links) (--mirrorlinks)
```

For the GUI version:

[image]

Comment: and how do i increase the limit?

Comment: i think i found it, options > limit > max links